# How to SUMIF on a dynamic range that includes blanks?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a column of numbers that I want to sum, but only under certain matched conditions, thus I've used `SUMIF` and `SUMIFS` with success. Now I want to make the range dynamic. Here's the working, non-dynamic, function:

`=SUMIF(B2:B60, "CC/*", A2:A60)`

Column B contains values that begin with "CC/" and Column A contains the values.

My new function, which works if Column B is sorted and contains no blanks between cells is:

`=SUMIF(OFFSET(B1, 1, 0, COUNTA(B:B), 1), "CC/*", OFFSET(A1, 1, 0, COUNTA(A:A), 1))`

The obvious problem here is that `COUNTA` returned how many fields have a value, and `OFFSET` returns that many fields, regardless of them being blank. Then my `SUMIF` function works on that data and returns an unexpected total due to the blank cells being present.

Here's an example table of data. The expected result of my `SUMIF` would be 3.00; however, the code above would return 1.00 because it `COUNTA` will return 2 due to the fact that there are only two non-blank fields in the second column.

```
     A       B
 +-------+--------+
1| Cost  | Source |
 +-------+--------+
2|  1.00 | CC/1   |
 +-------+--------+
3| 10.00 |        |
 +-------+--------+
4|  2.00 | CC/2   |
 +-------+--------+
5| 20.00 |        |
 +-------+--------+
```

P.S. I found this forum post that looked like it was what I'm looking for, but was having a hard time applying the concepts to my particular issue.

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/451089-count-blanks-dynamic-range.html

Comment: Your code returns 3 to me

Comment: `Now I want to make the range dynamic.`  What do you mean by this?

Comment: He means if a new raw is added, the sum would take that in considerations

Comment: Ala, you're correct. I wrote the table above as an example, I should've run it to verify it mimicked my exact situation. I'll try the suggestion below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be missing out on something, but can't this be accomplished by simply using open-ended ranges ?

```
=sumif(B2:B, "CC/*", A2:A)
```

Comment: I suppose so, you go down the rabbit hole and it's difficult to see the obvious solution. Originally though, I had the sums at the bottom of the columns. I've since moved them to the right.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there are no blanks in colA you can use:

```
=SUMIF(OFFSET(B1, 1, 0, COUNTA(A:A), 1), "CC/*", OFFSET(A1, 1, 0, COUNTA(A:A), 1))
```

Comment: Avoid Offset. It is volatile and will cause the whole file to recalculate any time any value is changed. It can lead to workbook slowness.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the text in column B as the criteria, the extents of the ranges should be the last row containing text in column B. Using the non-volatile [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) in place of the volatile [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) and the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) to find the last row containing text in column B the formula becomes,

```
=SUMIF(B2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH("zzz",B:B )), "CC/*", A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz",B:B )))
```

Comment: Definitely better than using volatile Offset.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by volatile offset? I'm new to the world of formulas.

Comment: I tried that :INDEX() syntax and Google Sheets doesn't recognize it, is this not supported in Google Sheets?

Comment: a) try searching for *excel volatile formula*; you will get the answer directly out of the search results. b) that's what happens when you mix-and-match *tags* to your question. I was answering an Excel question; seems you wanted a Google-Spreadsheet answer.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped. I just read a great article about it. So, do you happen to know what the Google Sheets alternative would be? They do have an `INDEX()` function